# Access variable from load function

Tags: jquery, function, variables, scope, global

here is a snippet of a function. I am getting the original size of each image. I then want to do a simple if statement but can't access the variable 'imageWidth'. Getting 'undefined' outside of the 'theImage.onload = function()'. How come it is out of scope?

```
    var parentWidth = $('figure.pack_image').width();
    var screenImage = $('figure.pack_image img');
    var imageWidth = '';

    screenImage.each(function () {

        var theImage = new Image();
        theImage.src = $(this).attr('src');

        theImage.onload = function() {
            imageWidth = this.width;

        }

        if (imageWidth > parentWidth) {
        ...
```

Answer (score 2):

It isn't "out of scope", it just doesn't have a value yet.  You can't test the `imageWidth` until it has been set, and the `.onload` call is asynchronous.

Your test needs to be started inside the `.onload` function:

```
theImage.onload = function() {
    imageWidth = this.width;
    if (imageWidth > parentWidth) {
        ...
    }
}
```

or, use deferred callbacks to de-nest the `onload` logic from the subsequent processing:

```
var gotImage = $.Deferred();
theImage.onload = function() {
    gotImage.resolve(this);
}

gotImage.done(function(img)) {
    if (img.width > parentWidth) {
         ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks. I had done your first solution previously but that created another problem. All done now though,

Comment: @user924248 I'm going to slightly rewrite the second version to pass the image object itself, instead of its width.  It'll make the method somewhat more flexible in the future.